# Error: Request has been terminated Only on React-Native

Tags: php, reactjs, react-native, cors

I was working on **iOS** application using **native-base**

```
request
      .get('http://url_with_query')
      .then(function(res){
        console.log(res.body.data);
      })
      .catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
      })
```

The Same Request working fine in **React** web application but not working in **React-Native**

> React-Native Debug Console - Result BELOW

```
Error: Request has been terminated
Possible causes: the network is offline, Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin, the page is being unloaded, etc.
    at Request.crossDomainError (client.js:616)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (client.js:724)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (event-target.js:172)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:534)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:378)
    at XMLHttpRequest.js:482
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:181)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:236)
    at MessageQueue.js:108
    at guard (MessageQueue.js:46)
```

> React Console - Result BELOW

```
Response {req: Request, xhr: XMLHttpRequest, text: "{"data":[{"stock":"in stock","min_sale_qty":5,"max…_description":"Consumer Products"}],"status":200}", statusText: "OK", statusCode: 200…}
```

> Destination URL headers

```
header("Content-Type:application/json");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
```